# Cannot find type [Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DacServices] error when installing Sitecore Commerce 9.0 Update-3

Tags: sitecore-commerce

I am trying to install Sitecore Commerce 9.0 Update-3 on my machine, but I am getting the following error.

> System.Management.Automation.PSArgumentException: Cannot find type [Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DacServices]: verify that the assembly containing this type is loaded.
>      at System.Management.Automation.MshCommandRuntime.ThrowTerminatingError(ErrorRecord errorRecord)
>   Invoke-DeployCommerceDatabaseTask : Cannot find type [Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DacServices]: verify that the assembly containing this type is loaded.
>   At X:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\SitecoreInstallFramework\Public\Install-SitecoreConfiguration.ps1:253 char:21
>   +                     & $entry.Task.Command @paramSet | Out-Default
>   +                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Invoke-DeployCommerceDatabaseTask

[image]

The assembly mentioned above is located in my machine "X:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DAC\bin\Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.dll".

I also have installed all the prerequisites mentioned in the documentation.

Has anyone been through this issue during Commerce installation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so it looks like the SIF script is hardcoded to look in C:\, and isn't dynamically changing the drive letter to x:\ for you.

If you look in "SIF.Sitecore.Commerce.1.4.7\Modules\DeployCommerceDatabase\DeployCommerceDatabase.psm1"

You will find the following two methods you'll need up update.

```
function GetSqlDacVersion
{
    # load in DAC DLL (requires config file to support .NET 4.0)
    # change file location for a 32-bit OS
    # param out the base path of SQL Server
    $sqlServerVersions = @("140", "130", "120", "110");
    $sqlCurrentVersion = ""
    $baseSQLServerPath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\{0}\DAC\bin\Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.dll";

    .........
}
```

and this one

```
function DeployDacpac
(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$dacpac, 
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]$connStr,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]$databaseName
)
{
    Write-Host "Importing DACPAC $($dacpac)"

    # load in DAC DLL (requires config file to support .NET 4.0)
    # change file location for a 32-bit OS
    # param out the base path of SQL Server
    $sqlServerVersions = @("140", "130", "120", "110");
    $sqlCurrentVersion = ""
    $baseSQLServerPath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\{0}\DAC\bin\Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.dll";

    ......
}
```

Can you update the path in both of these methods to be x:\ and try again?